# Sufficient conditions for minimum to exist in non-compact subset of normed vector space

Tags: general-topology, optimization, convex-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a non-compact subset of a normed vector space.  Let $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable convex function that is bounded from below. Given that $X$ is not compact:

1) Is there a simple sufficient condition on $f$ that guarantees that the infimum is attained within $X$, i.e., that there exists some $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = \inf_{y\in X} f(y)$?

2) Is there a simple sufficient condition on $f$ that guarantees that the infimum is attained within every non-empty convex subset of $X$?

Comment: If $f$ is a convex differentiable function defined on an open (convex) set, then $f'(x) = 0$ guarantees $x$ to be a _global_ minimum (maybe not strict).

Comment: Do you know if the existence of a global minimum guarantees that every non-empty convex subset will contain a minimum?

Comment: You mean convex and closed? Because the result will be clearly false if the convex set is not closed. And no, I do not know. In $\mathbf{R}^d$ you could use compactness but in general vector space, I am afraid I do not know.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I mean non-empty closed and convex subset.